# Python linalg.eig doesn't obey Perron-Frobenius theorum

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

Update:

It works with the `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs method`, but still not with `scipy.linalg.eigs`.

I have a real, positive, square matrix, and I am trying to find it's first (largest) eigenvector. Due to the Perron-Frobenius theorem, the largest eigenvector should have all positive entries, but in my case it doesn't. Here is my code for building the matrix:

```
def build_adj_matrix(G):
  matrix = np.zeros(shape=(34,34))

  for i in range(0,34):
    for j in range(0,34):
        if j+1 in G.adj[i+1]:
            matrix[i][j] = 1.00001
        else:
            matrix[i][j] = 0.00001

  return matrix
```

And here is my code for retrieving the eigenvector:

```
from scipy import linalg as LA
```

...

```
M = build_adj_matrix(G)
evals, evecs = LA.eig(M)
print(evecs)
```

my output is:

```
   [  3.55489549e-01 +0.00000000e+00j   3.86861181e-01 +0.00000000e+00j
   3.17170097e-01 +0.00000000e+00j   2.77301505e-01 +0.00000000e+00j
   5.54686086e-01 +0.00000000e+00j  -1.97848347e-01 +0.00000000e+00j
  -1.71390654e-01 +0.00000000e+00j  -1.42227261e-02 +0.00000000e+00j
   1.87538203e-03 +0.00000000e+00j  -6.71077427e-02 +0.00000000e+00j
   5.93338345e-02 +0.00000000e+00j   3.80034428e-02 +0.00000000e+00j
  -1.51430299e-01 +0.00000000e+00j  -6.33215778e-02 +0.00000000e+00j
   1.43005327e-01 +0.00000000e+00j  -7.33049336e-02 +0.00000000e+00j
  -1.64571850e-01 +0.00000000e+00j   5.91985880e-02 +0.00000000e+00j
  -1.31441525e-01 +0.00000000e+00j   1.35954155e-01 +0.00000000e+00j
  -2.30981270e-02 +0.00000000e+00j  -1.86533000e-01 +0.00000000e+00j
   7.84949962e-02 +0.00000000e+00j   9.41416444e-06 +0.00000000e+00j
  -1.92116017e-17 +0.00000000e+00j   1.10600656e-16 +0.00000000e+00j
   1.75023609e-17 -1.35088126e-17j   1.75023609e-17 +1.35088126e-17j
   4.75348687e-17 +0.00000000e+00j  -1.99584575e-18 +2.25485520e-17j
  -1.99584575e-18 -2.25485520e-17j  -6.78262748e-18 -8.13743189e-17j
  -6.78262748e-18 +8.13743189e-17j   8.83354389e-17 +0.00000000e+00j]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could run and try to reproduce the problem.  Something does not look right in your output: the code says `print(evecs)`, but the output is not a 34x34 matrix.  Is the output actually `evals` or just one row or column of `evecs`?

Comment: What's the determinant of M?  Is it close to singular?

Comment: For the output, print `evals[0]` and `evecs[:,0]`.

Comment: @hpaulj shouldn't matter here. Perron-Frobenius also applies to singular matrices. I suspect Warren is right and we are looking at a row here while the eigen vectors are stored as columns.